# Cargar dos o mas filas a un DataTable por medio de un Boton

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buen día a todos, estoy usando el siguiente método para cargar un `DataTable` que a su vez mostrara dicha información dentro de un `DataGridView`, el problema que tengo es que al oprimir el boton que debería agregar cada nuevo registro al `DataTable` y mostrarlo en el `DataGrid` solo me actualiza la información del primer registro y no me agrega el siguiente renglón, alguién sabe que estoy haciendo mal? adjunto el código.

```
public void CargarGrid()
{
    try
    {
        ObtenerValores();
        DataTable dtCGArt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtCGCte = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtGridArticulos = new DataTable();
        #region ObtenerArticulo
        if (artId>0)
        {
            dtCGArt = objConsultas.MuestraArticulosID(artId);
            if (dtCGArt.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow drCGArt in dtCGArt.Rows)
                {
                    articulo = Convert.ToString(drCGArt[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region ObtenerCliente
        if (cteId>0)
        {
            dtCGCte = objConsultas.MuestraClientesID(cteId);
            if (dtCGCte.Rows.Count>0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow drCGCte in dtCGCte.Rows)
                {
                    cliente = Convert.ToString(drCGCte[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
        dtGridArticulos.Columns.Add("Articulo");
        dtGridArticulos.Columns.Add("Cantidad");
        dtGridArticulos.Columns.Add("PrecioUnitario");
        dtGridArticulos.Columns.Add("Detalle");
        DataRow drArticulosSeleccionados = dtGridArticulos.NewRow();
        if (articulo!=""&&cliente!=""&&cantidad!=0&&preciounitario!=0&&descripcion!="")
        {                    
            drArticulosSeleccionados["Articulo"] = articulo;
            drArticulosSeleccionados["Cantidad"] = cantidad;
            drArticulosSeleccionados["PrecioUnitario"] = Convert.ToDouble(preciounitario);
            drArticulosSeleccionados["Detalle"] = Convert.ToString(descripcion);
            dtGridArticulos.Rows.Add(drArticulosSeleccionados);                    
            if (dtGridArticulos.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow drGridArticulos in dtGridArticulos.Rows)
                {
                    cantidad1 = Convert.ToInt32(drGridArticulos[1]);
                    preciounitario1 = Convert.ToDouble(drGridArticulos[2]);
                    if (cantidad1>0&&preciounitario1>0)
                    {
                        subtotal = cantidad1 * preciounitario1;
                        txtIngSubtot.Text = subtotal.ToString();
                        if (subtotal > 0)
                        {
                            subtotal1 = subtotal * IVA;
                            totalfinal = subtotal + subtotal1;
                            if (totalfinal > 0)
                            {
                                txtIngTotal.Text = totalfinal.ToString();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                txtIngTotal.Text = "0.0";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            txtIngTotal.Text = "0.0";
                        }
                    }
                }
                dgvListArtIng.DataSource = dtGridArticulos;
                dgvListArtIng.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                objValidaciones.MostrarAviso("Se agregaron los artículos de forma correcta.", false, lblAviso1);
            }
            else
            {
                dgvListArtIng.DataSource = "";
                objValidaciones.MostrarAviso("No se encontraron artículos en esta orden", true, lblAviso1);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}

private void btnAgregaArt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CargarGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que el problema esta en que cada vez que ejecutas la función CargarGrid() estas inicializando el datatable

```
DataTable dtGridArticulos = new DataTable();
```

Debes de declararlo fuera de la función como una variable global para que las filas se agreguen ya que cada vez que oprimes el botón al inicializar el dataTable las filas se borran.

Comment: Me lanza una excepcion: La columna 'Articulo' ya pertenece a DataTable.

Comment: Si porque en esta parte:    'dtGridArticulos.Columns.Add("Articulo");
        dtGridArticulos.Columns.Add("Cantidad");
        dtGridArticulos.Columns.Add("PrecioUnitario");
        dtGridArticulos.Columns.Add("Detalle");'    se agregan las columnas... eso debe estar donde declaras tu dataTable para que solo se agreguen una vez...

Comment: Tenías razon amigo, ademas de inicializar el DataTable cada que ocurría el evento el error estaba en que no estaba validando si la columna  ya exixtía para que solo me almacenara cada row.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Alberto,

Según he visto en el código que muestras, no tienes ningún bucle que vaya repitiendo el proceso de insertar las nuevas líneas dependiendo de lo que te hayan devuelto las funciones de datos, por lo tanto sólo se va a insertar 1 de ellas, ya que se va a recorrer el código una sola vez por `Click` al botón.

Deberías poner tódo el bloque de código dentro de un bucle para que se vaya repitiendo el proceso por cada línea de datos, por ejemplo así:

```
public void CargarGrid()
{
    try
    {
        //Hacemos un bucle para recorrer todos los datos que hay que actualizar
        //Por falta de información no puedo especificar el bucle, me lo invento
        while(condición)
        {
            ObtenerValores();
            DataTable dtCGArt = new DataTable();
            DataTable dtCGCte = new DataTable();
            DataTable dtGridArticulos = new DataTable();
            #region ObtenerArticulo
            if (artId>0)
            {
                dtCGArt = objConsultas.MuestraArticulosID(artId);
                if (dtCGArt.Rows.Count>0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow drCGArt in dtCGArt.Rows)
                    {
                        articulo = Convert.ToString(drCGArt[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
            #endregion
            #region ObtenerCliente
            if (cteId>0)
            {
                dtCGCte = objConsultas.MuestraClientesID(cteId);
                if (dtCGCte.Rows.Count>0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow drCGCte in dtCGCte.Rows)
                    {
                        cliente = Convert.ToString(drCGCte[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
            #endregion
            dtGridArticulos.Columns.Add("Articulo");
            dtGridArticulos.Columns.Add("Cantidad");
            dtGridArticulos.Columns.Add("PrecioUnitario");
            dtGridArticulos.Columns.Add("Detalle");
            DataRow drArticulosSeleccionados = dtGridArticulos.NewRow();
            if (articulo!=""&&cliente!=""&&cantidad!=0&&preciounitario!=0&&descripcion!="")
            {                    
                drArticulosSeleccionados["Articulo"] = articulo;
                drArticulosSeleccionados["Cantidad"] = cantidad;
                drArticulosSeleccionados["PrecioUnitario"] = Convert.ToDouble(preciounitario);
                drArticulosSeleccionados["Detalle"] = Convert.ToString(descripcion);
                dtGridArticulos.Rows.Add(drArticulosSeleccionados);
            }
        }

        //Cuando termina el bucle hacemos el siguiente paso
        if (dtGridArticulos.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow drGridArticulos in dtGridArticulos.Rows)
            {
                cantidad1 = Convert.ToInt32(drGridArticulos[1]);
                preciounitario1 = Convert.ToDouble(drGridArticulos[2]);
                if (cantidad1>0&&preciounitario1>0)
                {
                    subtotal = cantidad1 * preciounitario1;
                    txtIngSubtot.Text = subtotal.ToString();
                    if (subtotal > 0)
                    {
                        subtotal1 = subtotal * IVA;
                        totalfinal = subtotal + subtotal1;
                        if (totalfinal > 0)
                        {
                            txtIngTotal.Text = totalfinal.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            txtIngTotal.Text = "0.0";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        txtIngTotal.Text = "0.0";
                    }
                }
            }
            dgvListArtIng.DataSource = dtGridArticulos;
            dgvListArtIng.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            objValidaciones.MostrarAviso("Se agregaron los artículos de forma correcta.", false, lblAviso1);
        }
        else
        {
            dgvListArtIng.DataSource = "";
            objValidaciones.MostrarAviso("No se encontraron artículos en esta orden", true, lblAviso1);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en la forma que llenas el `DataGridView(dtg)` mediante el `DataSource` esto liga el `dtg` con la tabla, esto provoca que al momento de añadir un nuevo registro al `dtg` se limpia e insrta el nuevo registro. Por lo tanto tu solución seria utilizar otro método para añadir registro en el `dtg`. 
Ej:

Primero defines las columnas del `DataGridView` y luego realizas el `Add` por cada registro:

```
datagridview.rows.add("valorCol1","valorCol2","valorColn")
```

Y en el botón de nuevo registro, pones la misma línea de código, y veras que no se eliminaran tu anteriores registros:

```
datagridview.rows.add("valorCol1","valorCol2","valorColn")
```